# SpringXD and Spring Integration: Read from kafka topic every X minutes, then send to another Topic

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-xd

I'm trying to implement a solution to create a SpringXD stream composed by a kafka source, a bridge module, and a kafka sink.

So I have something like:

```
<channel id="pollable">
    <queue />
</channel>

<bridge input-channel="pollable" output-channel="executorChannel">
    <poller max-messages-per-poll="5" fixed-rate="5000" />
</bridge>
```

My problem is that I would like to avoid the poller somehow. Basically because I would like to avoid keeping messages in memory when those messages are in the queue. I would prefer to read from kafka every X minutes and just take Y message from the queue and send those ones to the next topic.

Looks like I can't get rid of the queue, but then my question would be:Is there another option? I don't like to keep stuff in memory, but I wouldn't want to use this option either: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#message-store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping the data in memory is NOT a good idea.

You can `stop()` and `start()` the channel adapter (`KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`) as needed; it will pick up where it left off when restarted.

However, the kafka source uses a very old version of spring-integration-kafka (1.3.x).

If you create a custom source to use spring-integration-kafka 2.1.0 (which uses the kafka 0.10.1.x client), you can set the kafka property `max.poll.records` to limit the number of records fetched.

Comment: What's the main purpose of a driven channel adapter? and  what's the main goal of a KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter? I have been trying to figure out what's the main purpose, reading the spring documentation, but it is not so clear for me. (I have been reading this: http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/_spring_integration.html#si-inbound and this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/kafka/Application.java) how should be the "flow" in my case?

Comment: Spring Integration is an implementation of [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/) you should familiarize yourself with that book and read the [Spring Integration documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/); it should answer questions such as yours.

Comment: Thanks!. After having read 2 articles about using message driven channel, I understood why to use it. I leave the articles here if some one else want to check:

First read this: http://www.javarticles.com/2015/01/example-of-spring-integration-using-service-activator-and-jms-inbound-channel-adapter-endpoints.html

Then this: http://www.javarticles.com/2015/02/example-of-message-driven-channel-adapter.html

Comment: How should I stop and start the channel adapter? I mean, how does the KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter use those methods? for example if I want to do this using xml?

Comment: You can't do it just with XML, you need custom logic in some java code; `@Autwire` the channel adapter and stop/start it as needed.

Comment: Ok, made sense. I did that. I know stop and start come from SmartLifeCycle class. So start/stop something can be done just adding my own logic. So my question should be: is there a sutiable way that I can use in between to stop/start the channel adapter?

Comment: You said you wanted to handle so many messages every few minutes. You could enable counts on the output channel and monitor the `sendCount` and stop the adapter when your required count is reached. The set a timer and restart after the timer expires.

Comment: Ok. Then in that approach you just mentioned, the `max.poll.records` wouldn't be necessary. Right? All in all, the **way** in which I implement the the moment when I start/stop it, depends 100% on me. There is no such a thing in spring, at this point, like something that "easily" handles when, for example to start/stop the channel adapter.

Comment: Correct; there is not a standard component with this functionality. And, yes, this technique will work regardless of the kafka settings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139297/discussion-between-columb1a-and-gary-russell).

Comment: Question, I noticed that I can't use max.poll.records in xml (using spring-integration-kafka 2.1.0) but I can use it using java config. So all in all, isn't a way to use it with xml config?

Comment: And Another question is, if this approach protects against keeping data in memory?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "can't use" - that's a kafka property passed into the consumer from a `Properties` bean. Yes, it avoids keeping data in memory (if you remove the queue channel).

Comment: My bad. you're right, I will accept your answer and close the question, because it is enough info to go ahead with what I wanted.