# SpringXD: auto-startup=false not working on Kafka message-driven-channel-adapter

Tags: spring, cron, spring-integration, spring-xd, spring-kafka

I'm using `SpringXD`, and I have the following config:

- spring-integration-kafka 2.1.0.RELEASE
- kafka-clients 0.10.0.1
- Kafka 0.10.x.x
- spring-xd-1.3.1.RELEASE

I have the following config in my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-kafka="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka/spring-integration-kafka.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">


    <int:channel id="input" />
    <int:channel id="output" />

    <int:control-bus input-channel="input" />

    <int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter
        id="kafka-inbound-channel-adapter-testing" listener-container="container1"
        auto-startup="false" phase="100" send-timeout="5000"
        channel="output" mode="record"
        message-converter="messageConverter" />

    <bean id="messageConverter" class="org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter" />

    <!--Consumer -->
    <bean id="container1"
        class="org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <map>
                        <entry key="bootstrap.servers" value="localhost:9092" />
                        <entry key="enable.auto.commit" value="false" />
                        <entry key="auto.commit.interval.ms" value="100" />
                        <entry key="session.timeout.ms" value="15000" />
                        <entry key="max.poll.records" value="3" />
                        <entry key="group.id" value="bridge-stream-testing" />
                        <entry key="key.deserializer" value="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer" />
                        <entry key="value.deserializer" value="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer" />
                    </map>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>

        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.kafka.listener.config.ContainerProperties">
                <constructor-arg name="topics" value="testing-topic" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

This is the Java class that I'm using to start/stop the channel:

```
package com.kafka.source.logic;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;

@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@ImportResource("classpath:/config/kafka-source-context.xml")
public class KafkaSourceRetry {

    @Autowired
    MessageChannel input;

    @Scheduled(cron="*/50 * * * * *")
    void startAdapter(){
        //CODE COMMENTED OUT TO MAKE SURE THE ADAPTER IS NOT BEING STARTED
        //EVEN IF I UNCOMMENT THE CODE, THE 50 secs defined related to the cron are not respected.
        //That is, if I send a message to the topic, it is inmediately consumed
        //input.send(new GenericMessage<String>("@kafka-inbound-channel-adapter-testing.start()"));
    }
}
```

Then I created a basic stream to check if some messages that I'm sending to the topic are coming through

```
stream create --name bridgeStream --definition "kafkaSourceLatestApi_v2|bridge|file" --deploy
```

I checked the file that was created, and it contained all the messages that I sent to the Kafka topic:

> hola_que_tal que_bonito  bridgeStream.out (END)

Also in the logs I found this:

> 2017-04-10T22:37:06-0300 1.3.1.RELEASE INFO
>   DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor -
>   Starting beans in phase 0 2017-04-10T22:37:06-0300 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG
>   DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor -
>   Starting bean 'container1' of type [class
>   org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer]
>   2017-04-10T22:37:06-0300 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG
>   DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor -
>   Successfully started bean 'container1' 2017-04-10T22:37:06-0300
>   1.3.1.RELEASE INFO DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Starting beans in phase 100
>   2017-04-10T22:37:06-0300 1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG
>   DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor -
>   Starting bean 'kafka-inbound-channel-adapter-testing' of type [class
>   org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter]
>   2017-04-10T22:37:06-0300 1.3.1.RELEASE INFO
>   DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0
>   inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter - started
>   kafka-inbound-channel-adapter-testing 2017-04-10T22:37:06-0300
>   1.3.1.RELEASE DEBUG DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - **Successfully started bean
>   'kafka-inbound-channel-adapter-testing'**

**My question is:** Why does the channel start automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's designed that way; all modules have auto startup set to false so they don't start out of order; when you deploy a stream, the individual modules are deployed and started right-to-left.

Deploy/Undeploy is the way to start/stop streams.

[See the `ModuleDeployer`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/spring-xd-dirt/src/main/java/org/springframework/xd/dirt/module/ModuleDeployer.java#L185).

Comment: Actually I don't want to deploy/undeploy the stream. What I want to do is stop/start the channel manually (so that is the reason I'm using the `message-driven-channel-adapter`. But looks like even I'm not starting manually it (using `@kafka-inbound-channel-adapter-testing.start()`) it simply started on its own.

Comment: I don't understand; if you don't deploy the module, how can you stop/start it? It's not "started on its own" Spring XD start()s it. After deploying, you can stop/start using JMX but there's no way to stop XD from starting it during deployment. If you are not deploying it to XD, why are you using an XD module? You can just use a spring-integration-kafka adapter directly. But your question says you are deploying a stream `stream create --name bridgeStream --definition "kafkaSourceLatestApi_v2|bridge|file" --deploy` - so your comment makes no sense to me.

Comment: If your question is "can I deploy a stream using standard Spring Integration components without starting it", the answer is no. You could write a custom adapter that ignores `start()` and uses some other mechanism to start.

Comment: Tbh I'm confused at this point. My stream is deployed. So far, so good. But I set my `message-driven-channel-adapter`  with `auto-startup=false`. So what I'm expecting (after my stream is sucessfully deployed) is the `message-driven-channel-adapter` won't receive any message until I do `@kafka-inbound-channel-adapter-testing.start()` . what is wrong with what I'm saying?

Comment: That's not the way it works - as I said `auto-startup="false"` is to prevent __spring__ from starting the module too soon during deployment. Instead __XD__ takes over the module lifecycle and starts the component at the right time during deployment. If you need different behavior, perhaps XD is not for you (or you need to customize the module as I described, to ignore the XD start command).

Comment: Mmm, Ok. So then, this answer shouldn't be valid anymore? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42987802/springxd-and-spring-integration-read-from-kafka-topic-every-x-minutes-then-sen

Comment: It's perfectly valid, you can `stop()` and `start()` the adapter at will, you just can't prevent the initial `start()` without customizing the channel adapter.

Comment: Ok, that's good. So, If after the stream is deployed, and using the cron I had defined, I do :
`input.send(new GenericMessage<String>("@kafka-inbound-channel-adapter-testing.stop()"))` it should work, right?. At least what I noticed, my adapter is still reading messages regardless this logic I just mentioned. Should I use something extra? (you mentioned JMX, but I'm not sure if I should use it, since I can use `@kafka-inbound-channel-adapter-testing.stop()`

Comment: It should work with the control bus; I suggest you turn on debug logging for `org.springframework.integration` and follow the control bus message. If you still can't figure it out post the log someplace like a github gist.

Comment: This is the log that I got: https://gist.github.com/columb1a/68e8d94c4bd95f0150cee5ee240a5068.
I changed the `input-channel` name related to the control bus to `input_to_control_bus`, and the `control-bus`  `id` is `my_control_bus`. The rest stays the same.

Comment: I don't see any activity on that channel; just `2017-04-11T14:03:14-0300 1.3.1.RELEASE INFO DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - Adding {service-activator:my_control_bus} as a subscriber to the 'input_to_control_bus' channel` - how are you sending the control operation?

Comment: This is what I did: I sent a message to the kafka topic. The message that I sent is `sending_a_message_to_topic`. To use the channel I did exactly what I posted in the description of this question, that is, I sent a message from my java class: `input_to_control_bus.send(new GenericMessage<String>("@kafka-inbound-channel-adapter-testing.start()"));`

Comment: There is no such message in the log so, no, you didn't send it.

Comment: Now I was able to to stop it. First of all I had to add a component-scan in my xml. That doesn't fix the issue, but the class was loaded. After that I removed the "-" from `@kafka-inbound-channel-adapter-testing.start()`(and obviously from the channel definition as well in the xml). 

This is the proof. I sent a message and first of all I saw when the channel was stoped, and also the message was not received:

https://gist.github.com/columb1a/5cac5de15e0b4fa6d81cc6663532a4f2

I have another question, But I would create a new SO question in order to not create off-topic stuff